# Pre-populate the duplicate questions dialog if a user flagged a post as a duplicate

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, duplicate-questions, moderator-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close as exact duplicate in flag review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111944/close-as-exact-duplicate-in-flag-review)

When a user exercises their 3k vote-to-close privilege and marks a question as a duplicate, the suggested duplicate is automatically shown to future closers, so that they can easily select it. When a user with <3k rep flags a question as a duplicate (using the built-in option which is identical to the close dialog), the link is shown in the flag, but the close dialog is not pre-populated with the suggested duplicate. It would be handy if the flagged dupe were shown as an option to users with >10k (as they can see flags) and to moderators, so that we could easily select that option when closing dupes which were only flagged.

Comment: Right click, Copy Link Address, Right click, Paste?

Comment: @sixlettervariables yes that works, and it's what we do now. But why not make it simpler? We go through a lot of flags every day.

Comment: You already have to click the link to view if its a dupe.

Comment: @shog I'm slightly miffed that this got closed as a dupe of a question which was asked later, but I suppose since Marc answered the other one it makes sense.

Comment: Heh... If I hadn't bothered to look up *when* it was implemented, I'd probably not have found the other question either.